# Definition of orbit of a group

Tags: group-theory, definition

I came across two definitions of orbit:

> **Definition1:** Let $p$
>     be a permutation of a set $A$ .
>   Let $\sim\subseteq A\times A$
>     be the relation defined by 
>   $$\forall a,b\in A\,\left(a\sim b\iff\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}:\,p^{n}(a)=b\right)$$
>   This is an equivalence relation (easy to check).
>   The equivalence classes of this equivalence relation are called the orbits of $p$ in $A$.
>
> **Definition2:** Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$ through an homomorphism $\pi:G\rightarrow S_{X}$. 
>   Let $\sim\subseteq X\times X$  be the relation defined by 
>   $$\forall a,b\in X\,\left(a\sim b\iff\exists g\in G:\,\pi(g)(a)=b\right)$$ 
>   This is an equivalence relation (easy to check).
>   The equivalence classes of this equivalence relation are called orbits.

I'm not seeing how these can be equivalent, or at least how one can be a particular case of the other. In the second case, the orbits are defined relative to a group, while in the first they are defined relative to an element of a group (the symmetric group)... So: is there a connection? How? Or are these two separate concepts that share the name?

Comment: See if [this post helps](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350415/equiv-relation-of-orbits-group-action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definition is the special case of the second where $G$ acting on $A = X$ is the cyclic subgroup of the group $\Sigma_A$ of all permutations of $A$ generated by the permutation $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The first definition is a special case of the second definition. For instance, if $p^n(a)=b$ then take a homomorphism $\pi:\mathbb Z\rightarrow S_X$ where $\pi(n)=p^n$ for the given permutation $p$. Then this induces the same orbits (equivalence classes) as the first case.